# Replacing plus sign "+" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trimming some strings but I am unable to do anything about the strings containing plus signs.

For example if I have this string with a telephone number

```
Dim str As String = "+46765124246"
```

And try

```
str.replace("+46", "0")
```

Nothing changes in the string.

Why is this and how do I do it?

Comment: Lots of people put effort into helping you out.  Deleting this question would result in them losing rep.  If your issue is solved by some other means, leave an answer with your solution and select it when the option becomes available.  Helps people who have similar issues and doesn't penalize those that tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

The replace function, and most sting functions are non-destructive. The original string is left alone. In order to work with the result, you need to assign the result back to a variable.

```
str = str.Replace("+46", "0")
```

or

```
Dim result as String
result = str.Replace("+46", "0")
Console.WriteLine(result) ' Prints '0765124246' str still equals '+42765124246'
```

Comment: Omg that was the only line I forgot do do it on wow I think I need to get some sleep *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Try...

str = str.replace("+46", "0")

Comment: Your suggestion would destory the original which is normally the best method.  The best solution would be to use a method which takes a string as a parameter and returns the new string which is then set to the original string.  value = FindString(value) for instance.